# How to differentiate the pressed button in later code?

Tags: javascript, php

I have trouble with this code..

I'm making a "zoo system", where using button click (its value=type of animal) it adds me new item (`<select>` of animals) of that type. The problem I have, is that I am not able to determine (because I'm using button, not submit and its $_POSTS), which of the 10 types of animals (10 buttons with different captions (e.g. "Add birds", "Add mammals", etc.) and different values of button) was "chosen" with the click.

And when I "Add birds", I'd like to create not only the `<select>` with particular birds, but I also want to create next element (e.g. next `<select>` with the color of its feathers). For each type, I'd like to have different element that I'd like to add to that stable `<select>`.

In my code, there's `newdiv.innerHTML = \"$animals[1]\";`, because it is working well if I manually put the value inside (it generates me select of animals with id_type=1).

```
$anim = array();
$res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY name");
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $anim[$arr['id_type']][] = "<option value='".$arr['id_animal']."'>".$arr['name']."</option>";
   $animals[$arr['id_type']]= '<select name=id_anim[]>' . implode(' ', array_values($anim[$arr['id_type']])) . '</select>';
}

$anim_type = "";
$types = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id_type, name_type FROM type_animals ORDER BY id_type");
while ($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($types)) {
    $anim_type .= "<button type='button' name='atype' value='".$t['id_type']."' onclick=\"zoo('dynamicInput', '".$t['id_type']."');\">Add ".$t['name_type']." </button>";              
}

echo"
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function zoo(divName, atype){
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = \"$animals[1]\";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
</script> ";
```

Do you think, it's somehow possible to differentiate which of the button was pressed so I can i.e. in JS have switch where for each number (value of pressed button, value of id_type), I can specify what content should be generated?

Or is it possible to generate content with PHP instead of JavaScript (so I can use something like $_POST - although it's just a button, not a submit)?

How can I use that passed value in JavaScript code, to generate more content due to that value? I see the foolish way, to manually insert 10 values, and for everyone set it's full content. But I'd like to see the smart way (i.e. the stable core, and the switch which generates its own content for each value)..

```
edit for @tttpapi: the generated code is:
stable: 4x <button type='button' name='atype' value='1-4' onclick=\"zoo('dynamicInput', '1-4');\">Add birds/mammals/beasts/herbivores </button>
generated after "birds" clicked: 
<select name=id_anim[]><option value='1'>Parrot</option> <option value='2'>Pelican</option> <option value='3'>Hummingbird</option></select>

And this all is, in latter code coated in:
<form method='POST'><fieldset>
<div name='dynamicInput'></div>
</fieldset></form>
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Can you show some of the generated HTML?

Comment: @tttpapi: I have added a generated code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the button click with

```
$button = $_POST["nameOfButton"];
```

Here replace "nameOfButton" with "atype".

Note: You need to put the same button name tag on the different buttons.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is gonna work. Those buttons are not submit buttons and I can't get its value (except as a JS paramater). If I add to code this `if (isset($_POST['atype'])){$button = $_POST['atype'];}` and in JS I'm gonna have `$animals[$button]`, it returns Undefined variable notice.